# Ubuntu 16.04, hdmi monitor: no signal in login screen

Tags: 16.04, display, hdmi, signal

My main monitor is connected over HDMI and my second one over DVI.

Both get a signal when the PC starts up, but the moment I get to the login screen the HDMI one goes dark, though it doesn't seem to lose the signal.  I can only get it to work again by unplugging and plugging in the HDMI cable again.

Interestingly, if I wait in the login screen until the screensaver starts and then move my mouse, both displays work.

How do I "refresh" the connection in the login screen?

Both monitors are connected to an AMD graphics card.

Comment: I just have been commenting on question: "https://askubuntu.com/questions/927639/external-monitor-hdmi-does-not-work-with-intel-hd5500-ubuntu-16-04". The poster commented the kernel was just updated to  4.8.0-56-generic.  Does you issue resemble this one in any way?

Comment: I don't think so, it works fine after I plug it in again and it gets detected as a hdmi connection. I restarted again, and I noticed I don't actually seem to lose the signal, the screen just turns black.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your keyboard, you should press the keyboard with the screen on it. PS : your may have to press several times and also configure the display resolution